# Having issues with an iOS react native native module using a CocoaPod

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, google-nearby, native-module

I'm creating a native module wrapper for the Google Nearby Messsages API.

I've installed the api using these instructions https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/ios/get-started

I then published the project to npm and created an example project to consume react-native-nearby.

I've been stuck with this issue.
[image]

I ran yarn to install react-native-nearby and react-native link react-native-nearby. Yet it can't find GNSMessages.h which should have been installed using cocoapods? Would be happy to get a lead as to why it can't find that file.

Comment: Are you definitely running the project from the xcworkspace file and not the xcodeproj file?

Comment: I'm not seeing an xcworkspace file just xcodeproj file. I've been running the project via the xcodeproj file. How does one get an xcworkspace file? This was created using react-native init.

Comment: Just to clarify. I do see an xcworkspace file in the native module ios directory (react-native-nearby/ios). I'm not seeing the xcworkspace file in (react-native-nearby/example/ios) <-- react-native project that's consuming the react-native-nearby npm package

Comment: After you set up Cocoapods for your project in the ios folder, you should have an .xcworkspace file there. Did you setup a Podfile and run `pod install` like they say in the link you refer to? Are you just running into this problem when running the project from Xcode or is it also happening when you do `react-native run-ios`?

Comment: https://github.com/miguelespinoza/react-native-nearby this is a link to the project. Just for reference. I'm having issues pushing my latest code. but 
the root directory contains the native module. 
index.js exposes the Nearby Native Module with ios and android directories.



I'm having issues with the example/ios directory  which is a react native project in their I'm not seeing the xcworkspace file. I'm trying to run the project using XCode so I can build it on a real device since I'm testing the Nearby api which requires a real device